# Why is built in Java BinarySearch returning only negative indices?

Tags: java, search, binary-search

Given State objects with parameters (a,b), I want to use java's binarysearch method to be able to quickly locate a State in an array. The States should be ordered first by increasing "a" values, and then "b" values if theres a tie. Also, all the States are distinct for simplicity.

The goal is to find how many pairs of states have opposite parameter values, or satisfy:

```
State 1 = (a,b)
State 2 = (b,a)
```

The test data below should output 1, pairing States 1 and 3 together. 
However, mine outputted 0, and debugging showed that all my bsearches returned negative values. Obviously two of them should have been positive

Main method:

```
/*
Test data (each state on a new line):
320 141
78 517
141 320
63 470
40 312
381 141
*/

    State[] states = new State[n];

    //Read in input (not shown)
    Arrays.sort(states);

    int ret = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        State other = new State(states[i].b,states[i].a);
             //search for state with opposite parameters

        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(states, other);

        System.out.println(index); //debugging purposes

        if (index > -1)
            ret++;
    }


    System.out.println(ret/2); //avoid doublecounting (a/b and b/a)
```

State class:

```
static class State implements Comparable<State> {
    int a,b; //State parameters

    public State(int a, int b) {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    public int compareTo(State other) {
        if (this.a > other.a) //first sort by "a" values
            return 1;
        else if (this.a == other.a && this.b > other.b) //"a" tie, now sort by "b"
            return 1;
        else 
            return -1; 
    }
}
```

Debugging yields the following indices:

```
-5
-7
-7
-6
-5
-5
```

Can anyone find the problem?

I'm pretty sure it isn't a duplicate. The poster there didn't sort his array beforehand, and was including whitespace in his bsearch key.

Answer (score 2):

Your `compareTo` method is broken.  The contract says that `this.compareTo(this)` should return `0`.  Your implementation never returns `0`.

A faulty `compare` or `compareTo` method is liable to cause the array to be incorrectly sorted, and/or lead to binary search failure.  With this specific fault, it is probably the latter.  The binary search can only "find" an element when the `compareTo` method returns zero.